# Android Change Background Color on Multiple Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

visual XML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz8Os.jpg

I have a xml with a linear layout inside of a relative layout. I have a custom background drawable to set the color of the background. However, I would like to have the main menu have a body of purple which is on top of a relative layout parent of white. How do I stack the purple layout on top of the white layout?

EDIT: I fixed it by removing the background color on the main parent relative layout and then setting the color of purple within the custom drawable background_menu.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Welcome" 
android:background="#694489"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:text="PATHING GAME"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttontype"
                android:text="START"
                android:layout_margin="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttontype"
                    android:text="HOW TO PLAY"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp" />

                                    <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttontype"
                    android:text="EXIT" 
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_background_menu"
```

to an ImageView that will seat behind the `linearLayout1`, so that the main RelativeLayout will have two children, the new ImageView and the existing `linearLayout1`. Then move the purple background to the `linearLayout1`, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_background_menu"/>

    <LinearLayout ...
        android:background="#694489" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

See if that helps